# How to remove anchor from external iframe widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I've embedded an external iFrame widget which also makes it clickable. Since I'm using this as a hero header, it's very strange if the entire thing links to an external page.

Therefore trying to remove the anchor and ideally also change the classes and id's.

```
<div id="thewidgetidname" style="background-image:url(https://theurltothesourcefile)" class="thecustomclass "><div id="thecustomid"><video id="anothercustomid" autoplay="" loop="" preload="" playsinline="" muted="" poster="" class="video landscape desktop"><source src="oneofthevariantsurl1" type="video/mp4">
<source src="oneofthevariantsurl2" type="video/mp4">
<source src="oneofthevariantsurl3" type="video/mp4">
<source src="oneofthevariantsurl4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
<a href="thelinkthatIwanttoremove" target="_parent" class="anotherclassthatIwouldliketochange">A text that I would like to remove or change</a></div>
```

I suspect that Javascript will be needed. I'm using wordpress with the Avada theme and Fusion Builder. I can inject code blocks and custom css. I'm not sure about the support for jQuery.

My own attempt was injecting the following codeblock, purely for removing the anchor attribute.

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName('anotherclassthatIwouldliketochange').removeAttribute("href");
</script>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you injected your code block into the iframe itself or into the hosting frame? Did your attempt work?

Comment: possible with same domain

Comment: @VytautasLozickas the iframe itself is embedded as a codeblock like this:
<div class="thisoneclassicanchangehere"><div style="position:relative; height:0; padding-bottom:56.25%; width:100%"><iframe style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;" src="mediasourcelink" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allow='autoplay'></iframe></div></div>